# The difference between "testament" and "will"

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, legalese

From what I found out in legal correspondence and deeds, it appears that "*will*" is used far more often than "*testament*". Is one more formal than the other? If not, what is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full name of the document is *Last Will and Testament*. One [definition](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Last+Will+%26+Testament):

> A document in which a person specifies the method to be applied in the management and distribution of his estate after his death.

*Will* is a common term to refer to this document. I wouldn't call it informal; I think it's what people use most of the time. In a legal context you're probably better off using the full name, though.

Answer (score 3):

Many legal terms use a pair of synonyms, one of Germanic origin, the other of Latin origin. This dates back to the Middle Ages, when a majority of the English population used Old English but many educated people (such as lawyers) spoke Old French or Latin. This developed into a habit of using such pairs even after the original motivation of expressing the same concept in two languages was lost. Such pairs are called [legal doublets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_doublet).

Examples: *aid and abet*, *cease and desist*, *kind and nature*, *will and testament*, …

*Will* (in this sense) and *testament* are synonyms. They can be used interchangeably (at least in normal speech, and I'm not aware of any legal difference). *Will* (the Germanic term) is a lot more common than *testament* (the French term).

Comment: I do not have knowledge in this field to determine whether this is correct, so I would not qualify to upvote it. But I must say, this answer is very enlightening. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

These days there is no distinction, but traditionally wills dealt with real estate, while testaments handled personal estate.  See, for example, [this page from the University of Nottingham](https://www.nottingham.ac.uk/manuscriptsandspecialcollections/researchguidance/deedsindepth/associated/will.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'm under the understanding that a will is what's in your mind as to what and who you desire to be as beneficiaries of your estate upon death, and testament is when the will becomes a legal document enforced by the law.